# NSArray Release crash

Tags: ios4, nsarray

In my code, i'm creating 5 sets of objects, and 5 NSArrays containing those objects. At the end of my method, two of the arrays release properly, but the other three crash my application.

Creating

```
UIImageView *image0 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TankAxe.png"]];  
NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image0, nil];

NSString *name0 = [NSString stringWithString:@"Pistol"];
NSArray *nameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:name0, nil];

NSNumber *price0 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:100];
NSArray *priceArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:price0, nil];

NSNumber *round0 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
NSArray *roundArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:round0, nil];

NSNumber *priceRound0 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]; 
NSArray *priceRoundArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:priceRound0, nil];
```

Releasing

```
[name0 release];
[nameArray release]; //Releases properly

[image0 release];
[imageArray release]; //Releases properly

[price0 release];
NSLog(@"%i",[priceArray retainCount]); //Returns 1
[priceArray release]; //Source of the crash

[round0 release];
[roundArray release]; //Also crashes

[priceRound0 release];
[priceRoundArray release]; //Also Crashes
```

Anybody know how to properly release the arrays containing NSNumbers?

Comment: Note that retainCount can never return 0.  One of the many reasons why you should never call that method.

Comment: Actually the app crashes if the retain count is 0 and the method is called, so it does help with debugging to call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

price0, name0,round0, and priceRound0 should not be released.  They were not created with alloc, and will be autoreleased by the methods that returned them.

Once you release an object that you shouldn't, the heap is corrupted, and the program could crash at any time.

The easiest way to debug this is to turn on zombies (Tip #1):

http://www.loufranco.com/blog/files/debugging-memory-iphone.html